# How to hide elements of an external widget on my website

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to instal a chat widget in my website and I would like to hide certain elements of the chat widget.

The chat is provided by Tidio but I guess this apply to any widget.

I am specifically trying to hide a button that minimise the chat button as highlighted in the image below.

[image: Button to hide]

I have inspected the button and found out that button has a class `exit-chat`, so I run this script where I try to get the button with `document.getElementsByClassName("exit-chat")` however the document is somehow null. I have also tried to add a delay before getting the button but it does not work.

Here is the code I have written and here is the link to a [codepen](https://codepen.io/max-2006tr/pen/PoBMOKg)

```
<script src="//code.tidio.co/fouwfr0cnygz4sj8kttyv0cz1rpaayva.js" async="async"></script>
  <!-- Swap your javascript code above -->
  <script>
     (function() {
      function onTidioChatApiReady() {
        (function() {
          //code run after the widget is loaded
          window.tidioChatApi.open();
          const loading = document.getElementsByClassName("loading");
          loading[0].style.display = "none";
          const tidioo = document.getElementById("tidio-chat");
          tidioo.style.display = "display";
            
          var timeoutInSeconds = 2;
            setTimeout(function() {
                    console.log("timeout");
                const minimizee = document.getElementsByClassName("exit-chat");
                    console.log(minimizee==null);
            minimizee[0].style.display = "none";
                    minimizee[1].style.display = "none";
            }, timeoutInSeconds * 1000)
            
        })();
      }
      if (window.tidioChatApi) {
        window.tidioChatApi.on("ready", onTidioChatApiReady);
      } else {
        document.addEventListener("tidioChat-ready", onTidioChatApiReady);
      }
    })();
  </script>

 <div class="loading">
    <p>Loading...</p>
 </div>
```

Can you please help to understand where I get this wrong and explain how to hide that button?
Thanks!!

Comment: If the widget is not contained inside an iframe then you could use css to hide the element(s).

Comment: As I understand it, the problem is that the chat popup along with the icon you want to hide is added to the DOM after the chat icon is clicked. Your code that does the hide should run after the chat pop-up appears.

Answer (score 0):

If you embedded an iframe that is hosted in another website, you will not be able to edit the style of the elements inside the iframe by adding CSS to your website.